# Reverse for 'add_comment' with arguments '(26, 34)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: python, django

I know this was asked before several times but I can't find the answer in any of the other questions.I'm getting this error : `Reverse for 'add_comment' with arguments '(26, 34)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []`.

In my `views.py` I have :

```
def add_comment(request, product_id, id):
review = get_object_or_404(Review, pk = id)
if request.method == 'POST':
    comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST)
    if comment_form.is_valid():
        comment = comment_form.save(commit = False)
        comment.author = request.user.username
        comment.save()
        review.comments.add(comment)
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('view_product', args=[product_id]))
```

In my `urls` I have (among other):

```
url(r'^profile/product/(\d+)/review/(\d+)/comment/$', 'core.views.add_comment', name='add_comment'),
```

and in my template I have :

```
<div class="comment_form row">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
        <form method = "post" action="{% url 'add_comment' product.id review.id %}">
            {%csrf_token%}
            {{comment_form|bootstrap}}
            <input type="submit" value ="Comment">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help.. I've been struggling with this for the last few hours.

Thanks

Comment: Is the URL is defined in main URL conf? or have you included app URLs in main URL conf?

Comment: The URL is defined in the main URL conf. Could it be related to the other URLs? Should I post them as well? I made sure there are no other URLs that point to the same view.

Comment: The ULR is coming from `core` app. In the [ROOT_URLCONF](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-ROOT_URLCONF) have you included `core` app URLs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56305/discussion-between-aamir-adnan-and-nevos).

Comment: Change `(\d+)` with `(?P<comment_id>[\d]+)` and `(?P<id>[\d]+)` respectively

Comment: @karthikr what is the difference between `[\d]+` or `\d+` they are both same pattern

Comment: Yeah they are. It is just that I feel `[\d]` is more readable, and consistent with regex patterns like: `[-\w]+`.(Just a coding preference) @AamirAdnan

Comment: @karthikr why comment_id? did you mean product_id?

Comment: Yup.. You got it.. Typo

Comment: But for sure `(?P<product_id>[\d]+)` will not change anything, its just that its named group now.

Comment: Full URL list could be found here : http://pastebin.com/q7V7bpD0

Comment: Do you have a namespace set ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't believe I'm saying this but the oldest trick in the book solved the issue, restarting. It seems like Django's web-server froze, therefore updating the URLs file resulted in nothing.
Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : I think I got it. You are trying to send parameters in URL with a POST method. I think you can send parameters in URL only with GET method. Use inputs (or hidden inputs) to give parameters using a POST method.

Example :

```
<form method = "post" action="{% url 'add_comment' %}">
            {%csrf_token%}
            {{comment_form|bootstrap}}
            <input type="hidden" id="product_id" name="product_id" value=product_id>
            <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value=id>
            <input type="submit" value ="Comment">
</form>
```

Then in views.py, remove the parameters :

```
def add_comment(request):
```

You can then access product_it and id with :

```
product_id = request.POST['product_id']
id = request.POST['id']
```

Don't forget to update your urls.py to match the method

Comment: Updated my solution ^